# For loop to end of array

Tags: c, arrays

I'm making `function`. To that function i send the `array` and then i need to write down that `array` with one space between characters in it .

How can i know is it end of array or not ?

```
 while (characters[i] != '0' ) 
{
printf(" %c");
i++; 
}
```

Edit

```
int i=0;
while (characters[i] != 0 ) 
{
   printf(" %c", characters[i]);
   i++; 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried looking *anywhere* on the internet? There are hundreds, if not thousands, if not hundreds-of-thousands of answers to this already.

Comment: != 0 (not '0') to recognize the end

Comment: C has no concept "end of array". By convention, arrays of characters are terminated with a single '\0' character (NOT '0'--that's the digit).

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Note that `'\0' == 0` by definition.

Comment: Yes, neither of which equals '0'.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker you mean strings of characters. Arrays are a fixed-size block of memory which may contain strings.

Comment: I don't consider what C does with characters to be "strings" like real string-handling languages have. It just has arrays of characters, some of which are interpreted as ending with '\0'.

Comment: VOTED TO REOPEN: This is not just a "please debug me" question. It's a "How does C handle arrays of characters" question, to which there is a good answer. It might be considered too basic, but I think many people learning C after some other language will have the same question.

Answer (score 3):

```
int arraySize = sizeof(characters)/sizeof(characters[0]);

for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
      printf(" %c", characters[i]);
}
```

Comment: Note: this only works if `characters` is an array, not a pointer. (It does answer the question as written)

Answer (score 1):

```
 while (characters[i] != '0' )
```

looks for the character 0 (which is x30). YOu need

```
 while (characters[i] != 0 )
```

or

```
 while (characters[i] != '\0' )
```

which looks for the character coded as  0x00.

Comment: The assumption being that the array contains a null-terminated string.